# Angular Form Multiple Input Binding

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form that can have any number of prescriptions, and I'm trying to data bind it to an array of objects. Except I'm always getting: `Cannot read property number of undefined`.

Here is my html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let num of [0, 1, 2]">
     <td><input type="number" name="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="prescricao[num].number" #number="ngModel"/></td>
</tr>
```

Here is my Angular component variable declarations:

```
export class MedicoComponent {
    prescricao: any[] = [];
```

And I'm always getting this error:
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined`

Any idea on whats wrong? I plan to have a lot more input after that, but basically in the end I want something like:

```
prescricao[
    {
         "number": 10,
         "idApr": 5
    },
    {
         "number": 5,
         "idApr": 3
    },
    etc...
]
```

Comment: Missing a semicolon after prescricao in your json

Comment: Details xD That Json is an arbitrary example of how I want it to look in the end after submitting the form

Comment: well you have no items in your array, so for example `prescricao[0]` is `undefined` just like error states.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sync two arrays, but it's hard to implement. Simply use original array in iteration:

`<tr *ngFor="let item of prescricao">
     <td><input type="number" name="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.number" #number="ngModel"/></td>
</tr>`

Comment: But does the declaration of prescricao stay the same? Because that way it doesn't create any lines in the table

Comment: @Adam, give value to prescricao in the ngOnInit